# Python: How to sort a list of dictionaries by similar keys

Tags: python

I have this data and would like to sort them like this

input:

```
[{'POINT': 0.1}, {'POINT': 0.2}, {'THRESHOLD': 0.1}, {'THRESHOLD': 0.4}, {'INDEX': 0.3}, {'INDEX': 0.9}]
```

I want the output to be like this

```
[
{'POINT': 0.1, 'THRESHOLD': 0.1, 'INDEX': 0.3},
{'POINT': 0.2, 'THRESHOLD': 0.4, 'INDEX': 0.9}
```

I have tried iterating over the list and keeping tracks of the keys but it doesn't seem smart to me.

Comment: can you elaborate a little further exactly what you want to happen

Comment: so giving that array of dictionaries with known keys, I want to arrange them where by each index is a dictionary with all the keys and values

Comment: How do you know which `POINT`, `THRESHOLD` and `INDEX` correspond to one another? Is it based on their order in the original list? Or might you need to sort them separately from one another? Are there only those three keys, or could the input have more or fewer?

Comment: the order at which the input array is generated is sorted, there will be more than three keys but the keys are known as they are stored somewhere in an array. The order at which the output should come out is based on the first occurrence of the keys. i.e, if there are 5 dictionaries of the same key, the first occurrence will be the first data

Comment: @RaheemAzeezAbiodun - so then have a look at my solution below, it works for both sorted values and values that need sorting (or any other type of processing). Consider accepting and upvoting :P

Comment: Thanks @rudolfovic I'm currently checking it out.

Comment: @rudolfovic how can I accept this as the answer. I have upvoted

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: done, thanks a lot. I really appreciate it

Comment: you're welcome and good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understood the problem setup correctly, you can do this:

```
pd.DataFrame({k: list(v.dropna()) for k, v in pd.DataFrame(x).items()}).to_dict('records')
```

This way values are used in the order they appear in, if you want them sorted, use `sorted` instead of `list`:

```
pd.DataFrame({k: sorted(v.dropna()) for k, v in pd.DataFrame(x).items()}).to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it does not have to be the list of dictionaries, you can display it in a pandas dataframe. That would also make it easier for you to do any task on your data.

```
import pandas as pd


l = [{'POINT': 0.1}, {'POINT': 0.2}, {'THRESHOLD': 0.1}, {'THRESHOLD': 0.4}, {'INDEX': 0.3}, {'INDEX': 0.9}]

result_d, keys = {}, []
for d in l:
    key = list(d.keys())[0]
    if key not in keys:
        keys.append(key)
        result_d[key] = []
        for d2 in l:
            key2 = list(d2.keys())[0]
            if key2 == keys[-1]:
                result_d[key].append(d2[key2])

print(result_d)
```

Output:

```
{'POINT': [0.1, 0.2], 'THRESHOLD': [0.1, 0.4], 'INDEX': [0.3, 0.9]}
```

Construct DataFrame from dict:

```
pd.DataFrame(result_d)
```

Output:

```
   POINT  THRESHOLD  INDEX
0    0.1        0.1    0.3
1    0.2        0.4    0.9
```